# Trimmed mean calculation in python

Tags: python, list, statistics, mean

I have a function to calculate the trimmed mean. To do this I use a new created list "**trimmed_list**".
But if **a** = **0**, the **trimmed list** will be empty because **s[a:-a]** does not work in this case.
Is there a way to fix the code without any imports?

Example:
With this code **tmean(x,0.2)= None**  instead of 29

```
x=[1,20,10,85]

def tmean(x, alpha):
  if alpha <0:
    raise ValueError("Alpha needs to be between 0 and 1")
  s = sorted(x)
  a = int(alpha * len(x))
  trimmed_list = s[a:-a]
  if len(trimmed_list) == 0:
    return "No calculation possible"
  trimmed_ave = sum(trimmed_list)/len(trimmed_list)
  return float(trimmed_ave)
```

Comment: you try to calculate mean of selected elements by range[1, len(x)]? How you get result `29`?

Comment: In this case  the "trimmed list" = normal list "x" because a = 0, so 116/4 = 29

Comment: But my code the trimmed list= [ ] because **-a** doesn't work

Comment: but you need to calculate mean value from slice of list.  Alpha=0 mean empty list and Alpha=1 means all elements of the list? Can you post few more examples to show how the trim should work? Or what are expected results for certain input and why.

Comment: alpha shows the percentage how much you trimm the list, e.g. 0.2 means you want to cut 20% from the left and the right site of the sorted list. With only 4 elements in a list 20% means you cut nothing so you build the normal mean. With alpha=0.3 the trimmed list would be [10,20] and the trimmed ave= 15 (30/2)

Comment: hblanc28 then Alpha should by in range [0,0.5)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a simple `if` condition to check if `a` is `0`.

```py
x=[1,20,10,85]

def tmean(x, alpha):
    if alpha <0:
        raise ValueError("Alpha needs to be between 0 and 1")
    a = int(alpha * len(x))
    if a == 0:
        return sum(x)/float(len(x)) # return mean
    s = sorted(x)
    trimmed_list = s[a:-a]
    if len(trimmed_list) == 0:
        return "No calculation possible"
    trimmed_ave = sum(trimmed_list)/len(trimmed_list)
    return float(trimmed_ave)
```

Hope this helps.